# userContent.css and Internet Explorer 8 or higher

Tags: internet-explorer, stylesheet, accessibility

I am trying to use the "userContent.css" file as a User Style Sheet, as specified in Internet Explorer, Tools, Accessibility option.

I have found that although CSS styles as they may appear in an external style sheet, style sheet block in HTML, or inline use of style="" in HTML, they do not seem to work in a User specified style sheet under the Accessibility option of IE.

Below is an example:

```
#myID, .myClass { color: blue !important} 
/* this works for id's and classes in the userContent.css file */

[id="myID"] { color: blue !important}
/* this fails for a User specified style sheet (userContent.css) */
/* but works as inline, block or in an external style sheet */
```

This all started in my attempt to use a "universal" or "wildcard" to specify
many div's with an id that started with "myID".

What I want to do is this:

```
div[id*="myID"] {color:blue !important}
```

Again, this works with inline, block or external CSS file style, but not in a file referenced in IE under Tools, Options, Accessibility, User Style Sheet.

I've read plenty of documentation on CSS uses but I can't find anything for the accessibility file use of CSS styles.

Comment: Could you give us a sample url where it does not work, and the matching css?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="myClass="background-color:red">User Content Testing</div>
    <div id="myID" style="background-color:red">User Content Testing</div>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: it works for me in IE11; i only had to close the window, and reload the url...

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and lower does not understand CSS3 selectors like "contains selector" `*=` but it should work with higher version. It works as expected in IE11.

Comment: Is there any documentation on the css "rules" for the Accessibility file?

Comment: In my recent test with IE8, [myID*=...] worked with inline, block or external reference in HTML, it's just not working in the Accessibility file userContent.css. Even the simple [id=myID] is not working.
This may have something to do with how IE interprets the Accessibility file.